# What could cause severe under-exposure when using a Canon 5D Mark III with Speedlite 600EX-RT with Evaluative E-TTL2 metering?

Tags: flash, exposure, hotshoe-flash, canon-5d-mark-iii

I recently purchased a Speedlite 600EX-RT for use with my 5D Mark III.  I'm shooting with a 17-40 f4/L lens.  Particularly when using the flash in the standard forward position, I get extremely severe underexposure when shooting in P mode with the flash in either High Speed Sync or First Curtain release with E-TTL2 on in evaluative mode.

There are perhaps one or two fringe areas of the image that are exposed (less than 3% of the total image) and none of them are at all close to the chosen focal point.  Many images haven't even had any portion of the image properly exposed.  I'm using Center Weighted Average Metering for my metering setting.

Any idea what could be causing the issue?  Does the metering setting for the camera and the flash have to match for proper results?  Is there simply an issue with the communication between the flash and camera body?  I'm really not sure what is going on and why I'm getting such poor results with the flash.  I notice it also seem to do much better when using the flash in a bump flash configuration.

Edit: As mentioned below, I do realize there is a flash exposure compensation adjustment in the flash that I can make to boost the exposure, but I'm trying to figure out why it is misbehaving rather than simply trying to work around the problem.  I'm specifically looking for any additional insight in to what could be making it underexpose by multiple stops.

[image: JPEG sample without any correction done]
[RAW File (CR2) as Shot](http://www.ajhenderson.com/flash_problem/OH2A3618.cr2)

Comment: What types of subjects are you photographing and could you post a sample image?

Comment: I agree with the above: without examples, it's hard to pinpoint the issue. Try a shot in evaluative metering as well as center-weighted metering for exposure, too. Maybe e-ttl2 metering on the flash and cwa metering on the body are fighting each other for correct exposure?

Comment: I have a limited subset of images to work from so far, but I will try to get a couple of them up.  My initial review (only looked at them in camera so far) seemed to be fairly consistently off, but it is still disconcerting that it is off so severely (multiple full stops, most of the image is almost black).

Comment: A few example images would be very helpful. Also, are you using a 14-40mm L lens, or the 17-40mm L lens? If Canon is making a 14-40mm f/4 L-series lens, that would be pretty hot news. I am pretty sure you mean the 17-40....just wanted to make sure.

Comment: @jrista yes 17 to 40mm.  Sorry, not sure why I was thinking 14.

Comment: Sample's posted.  I did notice that There is detail in the image if I bring up the exposure in Lightroom, so perhaps the problem is actually in the way that the camera is deciding to adjust the image after taking the picture.  But then again, I don't do a lot of low light stuff at 400 ISO, so I'm not really sure what an image generally looks like when the exposure is bumped up on one.

Comment: When I see the image, it does not look unexpected. I think I know what has happened. The camera is trying to fill the scene (fill flash) and does no succeed. One issue in dark environments is that the subject is overexposed while the background is black. I'm not sure what could throw off the metering though. you are not using a diffuser or "strange filter" and you are not in HSS, are you?

Comment: @DetlevCM I was using high speed sync I think.  I had not played with that before so if it can cause issues, I'll switch to First Curtain.

Comment: If I am not making a mistake, it is HSS that is used for fill flash and this looks like fill flash to me. Still, the camera shouldn't get it wrong, but it is a first consideration.

Comment: @DetlevCM - looks like HSS shouldn't have kicked in since the shutter was slower than the maximum sync speed.  I did find another article complaining that the 5D Miii has issues with the flash in Evaluative mode and suggested using Average metering, so perhaps there is just a bug in the metering firmware.  I haven't had a chance to verify yet if it makes a difference.

Comment: My understanding of HSS synch is that it is a "stroboscope like" flash, while second or first curtain flash is a single discharge. Hence, if you manually dial in HSS, it will use that at slow shutter speeds as well.

Comment: @DetlevCM - you are correct about the stroboscopic flash, but it only functions at speeds in excess of the sync speed.  Below sync speed, the detailed resource I found about HSS said that both Canon and Nikon fall back to standard flash automatically. http://www.rpphoto.com/howto/view.asp?articleID=1026

Comment: @AJHenderson I don't believe that quite adds up. High Speed Synch will still give you a stroboscopic flash at slower shutters - and act like fill flash. But simple 1st or 2nd curtain will not give you fill flash. (I looked through the article as well - but try a different flash mode. The subject should then be correctly exposed and the background should be dark - notice the comment about losing a stop of light with HSS?)

Comment: @DetlevCM - yes, that is because of the strobe being less powerful when having to flash quicker, however the HSS isn't supposed to be stroboscopic since HSS was specifically designed to work with the rolling shutter problem for shots above the sync speed.  A stroboscopic flash is useless if a normal flash can be used since it will still expose the entire image.  A fill flash simply needs the light on target, it doesn't matter if it is applied over the entire shutter time (and in fact, for shutters like 1/30 of a second, it couldn't actually keep the strobe up long enough).

Comment: Well, the thing is though, 1st and 2nd curtain will look different to HSS in the actual image - at least in my experience. -> HSS supplies fill flash while the others do not and just light up the target.

Comment: @DetlevCM  isn't fill flash simply a flash that illuminates the subject when backlit (or lit from some other angle)?  In this case, a single moment of intense flash versus many lower power flashes is going to achieve a similar result as the intense burst of photons will develop similarly to a lower powered stream of them, just the burst will have better motion stopping properties, which is generally desirable.

Comment: Well it appears that I have been unable to reproduce the issue I was experiencing that night in a controlled environment at home.  No matter what settings I choose, I get uniform, if somewhat dark exposures, but are certainly within the range of what I'd consider a standard exposure.  First curtain or HSS, Average or Evaluative metering (on the flash), any metering on the camera, all produce roughly equivalent (and ok) results in a partially darkened room at home.  Perhaps there was something weird about the lighting in the room that was causing the issue.

Comment: @AJHenderson My understanding of fill flash is flash that fills the whole (or most of the) scene with light more than just illuminating the key subject. Though using flash to light up a subject when shooting into the sun will have the same effect.

Comment: @DetlevCM - fill derives from three point lighting (key, fill and back).  It isn't trying to fill the image with light, but rather acting as a secondary light which fills in the shadows left by the key light.  The purpose of this is to compensate for the limited dynamic range of an imaging sensor which would normally make shadows too harsh.  I known this is how Key and Fill apply in the lighting world, so I don't know why flashes would take a different meaning to the same word.

Comment: HSS will result in much, much less light being thrown. If the shutter speed is above 1/200 or so, the flash my be using HSS, which will limit the distance dramatically. Also, ETTL will respond to the eval mode and metering. Try spot metering, to force the computer to evaluate on your primary subject only. The subjects getting blown out might also be impacting the metering

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have had identical issues with the 580 ex II.

Change the flash setting in the cameras menu to 'average' not evaluative it fixes it. I don't use evaluative for the camera settings without the flash either the same issue happens and photos under exposed. I think Canon need to revisit their 'evaluative' system.

Hope this helps....

Answer (score 2):

I also have had problems with both the Canon 5D Mark II and Mark III with the Speedlite 430, 580, and now the 600, so there is a fundamental problem with the handshake between the camera and the flash.  Most recently I was shooting a wedding and the exposure was consistently around 2 stops under and looked just like the underexposed photo from the OP.  I did a reset on the flash function settings in the camera to no avail.  The camera continued to shoot as if the flash was firing at proper intensity.  Normally the camera will set the camera up to be about 2 stops low then the flash brings it up to proper intensity.  This gives a properly exposed and frozen in motion image that is good for most and keeps the background reasonably well lit.  It normally gives good results but for some reason, the handshake does not let the flash come up to full power and it flashes only at the 2 stops lower intensity of the background.  The ONLY way to rectify this is to force a re-handshake between the camera and the flash.  The easiest way is to put it on another camera body and this seems to fix it in an instant.  Putting it back on the original body brings all back to normal operating again.  Somebody had mentioned putting it on average rather than evaluative metering for the flash but I have never tried that but in theory it might work if the camera and flash talk during that switch.  It is not a good situation for sure and in the past, putting previous flashes and cameras onto the green square fixed it. That is not the case with the Mark III and the Speedlite 580 or 600 flashes.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I can help, but sorry if my English isn't grammatically right :)
I got my mark iii yesterday and had the same problem with flash and under exposing.
At first found that the camera exposes correct if I use the preflash button before I take the shoot. Second I found that the exposure is correct if I set the flash to master. 3rd, the thing with the master setting seems to have solved the problem, because now I get correct exposures in any settings. I'm not a computer specialist but my only idea how this could have happened is, that somehow my yongnuo wireless ettl trigger changed something in my 580 ex ii, wich I set back while setting the flash to master for one time.
Hope you understand what I exactly mean and hope I could help.
Best wishes from Austria,
Mario

Comment: Thanks, that sounds similar to Frank Sanns' answer.  (Basically that some internal state gets screwed up and reconnecting/resetting/changing modes can reset the state.)  Switching to Master shouldn't have done anything particularly different other than possibly resetting the internal state of the flash.  I use Canon's wireless system and had the flash in Master mode at the time I had the problems, but switching it to stand alone mode may have worked to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are off by a consistent amount on different images of similar settings, have you considered exposure compensation? I think there is a secondary setting for the flash compensation as well if I am not mistaken.

Comment: There is a flash exposure compensation setting and it is off by a consistent amount, so this can work as a fix, but with it being so severely off, I'm more worried about why it isn't working correctly for such high end gear.

Comment: Well, without examples it is hard to judge. Some people will calll a difference of 2/3 of a stop severe, or 1/3 of a stop. Alternatively it might be 2 stops out... - the flash is definitely firing? It is also fully charged? (On my EX430 II, if I snap too many images I might shoot an image without flash which then is too dark.)

Comment: I'm getting some of the images posted now.  The flash is definitely firing and I'm using the Canon CP-E4 extended battery and not doing rapid bursts.  So I'm fairly positive that it is fully charged. (Full charge takes less than half a second with the CP-E4.)  It's not 1/3 or 2/3 of a step off, it is more like multiple full steps off.  The image is nearly black.

Comment: Well, the example is maybe one stop off (at a guess) but good to know you checked those points. It means more points to eliminate. Having said that, I have a suspicion...

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that you started firing off shorts before the flash was ready.  It has happened to me before and makes the images severely underexposed.  It happens if the battery power is low or if you have been firing off a lot of flashes and the flash needs time to recycle.

You said that you were not able to reproduce the issue?  Did you happen to put new batteries on them?  Did you use the flash with the same intensity as before?

Comment: This wasn't the problem unfortunately.  I had new batteries in, was not firing rapidly and also had the CP-6 battery pack in use so my cycle times for full charge were under 1/3 second.

Answer (score 1):

The image seems to be quite underexposed indeed. Even the brightest spots seem not to be bright enough to me, so there must be something else. 
The flash has enough power to cover the distances in the picture, power should not be the problem.
Broken mechanical parts (aperture blades, metering sensor, etc.) could maybe cause the problem, but that would be weird and seems not very likely to me.

With just one picture and the given information, I think it is a software problem in or between the camera and the flash. When the amount of underexposure is constant, you could just add an amount of 'overexposure', when the amount of underexposure differs at different pictures I should go to the store and say the product does not work properly.

Newest firmware of the flash and camera is installed?

Comment: Yeah, I was leaning towards something like this.  I found some other people posting about similar issues.  I haven't been able to reproduce it since then though and I'm hoping that the April firmware update for the camera body may not have the problem if it is just some weird edge case.

Answer (score 1):

Cause 1:
What is the shutter speed you are using? 
Try to use 1/1-1/250s, do not exceed 1/250s.
Heres what will happen if you exceed 1/250s(example 1/640s), if the flash is manual the result will black area on upper portion of the image due to the flash not being able to keep up with the closing of the shutter.  But if your flash is ETTL and has HSS(high speed sync) it will result in an underexposed image.  Here a link I found about HSS, it has sample images. http://neilvn.com/tangents/high-speed-flash-sync/

Cause 2:
Are you using 2 flashes, 1 master(on camera) and 1 off camera?
Heres the catch,let put it this way, 600rt is your master, so we assume you are using ETTL. Using ETTL, the camera will control the output of the flash base on available or ambient light. And your off camera flash is on manual and not ETTL. If the output of the off camera flash is stronger than on camera flash, it will result on an underexposed image. 
    Solution:
      1.If the off camera flash is on manual triggering, lower the power,until you get the desired result.
      2.Use triggers that support ETTL.
      3.If you are using optical slaves, there are 2 modes, S1 = manual optical slave(you have to set the power manually) and S2 = ETTL optical slave( I'm using this when I use my built in flash to trigger an offcam flash).

Cause no. 3:
Maybe there is a problem with your ETTL reading, try resetting the camera.

Comment: While the first two situations were not applicable to my shot. They are good general advice for avoiding exposure problems with flash, so still +1.  Note that HSS should achieve proper exposure if the flash had enough power.   Also a manual full power flash that doesn't scale down can cause a few different issues depending on if you use full power pre flash. The under exposure comes from the camera assuming that the off camera flash was at partial power for preflash.  If it doesn't preflash,  TTL will over expose. If it full power flashes but the camera thinks it was partial you get a mix.

Answer (score 0):

[caveat: I am not a Canon expert]

#### Image

From the photo it appears that the flash is firing at a low power setting, e.g. the reflection over the skinny man with a tie center frame, various pieces of jewelry, etc.

#### Scene

By all appearances the scene appears to have relatively little ambient light and therefore wide aperture, slow shutter and high ISO are implicated as appropriate compensations. On the other hand, a shutter speed that would require high speed sync is contra-indicated and the scene does not suggest motion where first curtain  sync would matter.

#### Technology

My understanding is that Evaluative Mode is primarily intended to provide infill light rather than the primary light source. To the degree that's true, the camera aperture, shutter speed, and ISO must be appropriate for shooting with the ambient light.

My understanding of Canon's P-mode is that it allows setting the ISO to a fixed value and constrains shutter speeds to avoid camera shake, i.e. there is a lower bound on shutter speed regardless of available light.

#### Analysis

The combination of preset ISO and lens maximum aperture require a shutter speed low enough to create blur due to camera movement. P-mode's "safety" features to prevent blurring from camera shake are raising the shutter speed and over-riding the intent of the flash settings.

Compensating for camera shake has to be done "just in time" or at the last (fraction of a) second so over-riding the flash intent in P-mode makes some reasonable sense given that the alternative is a blurred image. Keep in mind that the point of P-mode and other automatic modes is to reduce the likelihood of very poor images not to produce great ones and to increase the likelihood of capturing acceptable images. Cynically, it's to prevent having to deal with "my camera is broken" complaints from consumers using complex technology.

#### Conclusion

At a high level, the "what is going on" is that the camera is deciding what is best and because evaluative metering in a low light scene under program mode with a speed light set to high-speed/first-curtain sync is an edge case, it produces its best attempt at an acceptable image. Really knowing what is happening in this circumstance requires understanding implementation details deep down in the software at a level that the programmers themselves may not fully understand.

To me, accurately reasoning out the corner cases of P-mode is harder than reasoning about the scene and setting the camera and speedlight manually because the software can have bugs and light does not. To put it another way, understanding causal relations in P-mode is harder than understanding causal relations with manual settings because it requires understanding vagaries of the program in addition to knowledge of optics and a feel for the light in a scene.

Comment: My understanding is that the main point of evaluative metering is that it uses the focus point as the "center" and functions somewhat similarly to center weighted average, but with understanding of where the subject is.  It is still worth noting that this may be part of the problem as this image's focus is somewhat off.  It identified a zone that is mostly black as the focus, so it is possible it determined it could not properly expose the focus area and basically gave up.  That said, the shake adjustment theory is another interesting one, though 400 is a pretty low ISO to be going to shutter.

Comment: @AJHenderson I did a bit more digging based on your comment and am working through a revised answer. Evaluative metering as finding the subject has the effect of creating infill...so I don't disagree with your description: it's a good way of looking at it.